# Performance slowdowns when compiling with coverage

Tags: gcc

After enabling coverage (using `--coverage` in compile and link), I've noticed that my application is running ~10x slower than previously. This seems really large... I was expecting more 1.5-2x slowdown. Is this expected? If not, what could the issue be?

The application is parallelized and math-heavy. I'm not sure what additional information to provide. Could parallelization cause problems by requiring each thread to grab a mutex before updating the coverage database?